# Button in a customized listView is not working properly?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my application I'm using customized listView with **Text view** and **Button** to change the button image. After I click the button in 1st position, the image of the button changed but when I scroll down the listView, the image set changed to some other position.

```
 public class CustomListViewAdapter_ringtone extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
Activity activity;

public CustomListViewAdapter_ringtone(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

class ViewHolder {
    Button play;
    TextView tarck_name,singer;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final ViewHolder holder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tarck_name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.track_name);
        holder.singer = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.singer);
        holder.play = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.play_pause_btn);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
    holder.tarck_name.setText(map.get("track_name"));
    holder.singer.setText(map.get("sing"));

    holder.play.setTag(position);
    holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            holder.play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausebtn);

            //here am set the background for the button but when i scroll down the image changed to some other positon
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}   
}
```

Comment: You have to create an object that save the state of your selected Items. See the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964401/using-viewholder-interface-to-update-state-to-listview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this is will help:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.tarck_name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.track_name);
    holder.singer = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.singer);
    holder.play = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.play_pause_btn);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
```

Comment: But yout write  if (convertView == null) { ...} else {...}

Comment: am try your code its not working.after i scroll down that image will be cleared its not maintained the state.